# Can i use a test framework like testNG in RIDE with RobotFramework?

Tags: testng, robotframework, ui-testing, robotframework-ide

I'm using robot framework with RIDE in order to automate a desktop windows application.
Is there any way that i can use test frameworks like `TESTNG` because i need to make dependences between tests and many other features related to this framework.

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

`RIDE` is a Robot Framework files editor and supports running those tests, using the Plugin Test Runner. It does not allow to edit `Java`, `Python` or even `YAML` files.

There are some options to "call" `TestNG runner`, but it is not integration:

- In your tests steps add calls to Process or OperatingSystem Libraries to run the TestNG files
- Use the `Run Anything` Plugin to define `TestNG runner` scripts
- Create library (`Java` or `Python`) which acts as a wrapper for calling TestNG

(Eventually do some post-processing to integrate `TestNG` outputs with Robot Framework's, by using `rebot`)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, it's helpfull :)

Comment: what you mean by it is not integration? it's not possible to make a continous integration with it do you have a link how to make those steps ?